# Is "eipher" a proper English word or a typo of "Cipher"?

Tags: meaning, etymology

In many posts and online articles, I come across the usage of "eipher". But, I could not get the meaning or history of this word from any sources.

The word "eipher" results many Google search results, but nothing useful found.

**Examples:**

> Other telegrams in eipher say the rumor is current that he has been
> strangled.
> Source: https://www.nytimes.com/1876/06/01/archives/latent-news-by-cable-the-turkish-revolution-rumored-death-of-abdul.html

> It grids us with the belt of wisdom, and imparts to us the eipher of
> life.
> Source: "Bible Gems" book. Page 108
> https://books.google.ae/books?id=hpFfF3K4Wg4C&pg=PA108&lpg=PA108&dq=eipher&source=bl&ots=N3XUTXI_3O&sig=ACfU3U0m4ImKhZQHMwY6cny2I7ghRlPbVg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiL5_e5zPvzAhWLnRQKHd8fD004WhDoAXoECAkQAw#v=onepage&q=eipher&f=false

Comment: Please include some examples of the use of the word, with citations.

Comment: Updated in the question.

Comment: I'd say that the second example is almost certainly an OCR error and should be cipher. The first is behind a paywall but from context would also seem intended to be cipher.

Comment: Note that searching Google isn't going to help verify anything, other than finding that many have made the same mistake.

Comment: In the *Bible Gems* example, it's easy to see how such an OCR error could occur; compare other Cs near the right margin where the scan is blurred.

Comment: What did your dictionary say when you looked up the word "eipher"?

Answer (score 4):

These are both OCR errors where the letter *c* has been confused with *e,* possibly due to a poor original sample.

Comment: Yes, a quick look at Bible Gems reveals the word "gird," not *grid*, and the C in cipher is right there, too.